# How to improve search speed of a query in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

The host is AWS from ElasticSearch, I have 2TB of data stored in 6 nodes and in 30 indexes with 10 shards each. A simple search in all indexes is very very slow and takes a few minutes.

Where I made the mistake? Is that normal or I have bad settings or maybe I have too much data stored?

My cluster settings:

```
"search": {
     "max_queue_size": "1000",
     "queue_size": "1000",
     "size": "4",
     "auto_queue_frame_size": "2000",
     "target_response_time": "1s",
     "min_queue_size": "1000"
},
```

My nodes settings:

```
"os": {
     "refresh_interval_in_millis": 1000,
     "name": "Linux",
     "pretty_name": "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)",
     "arch": "amd64",
     "version": "4.15.0-1039-aws",
     "available_processors": 32,
     "allocated_processors": 2
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Opster! I still search for a solution. :)

Comment: @Opster https://checkups.opster.com/tools/checkup/report/c3RhbmdhY2VsQGhvdG1haWwuY29t/1598450417131

Comment: Thanks for your report link, will look into it and get back to you,

Answer (score 3):

Its a very broad question with very less information, can you please provide more information like:

1. How much data you have and size of each shard.
2. Sample search queries with their avg time taken.
3. data nodes heap size and why you have `allocated_processors` very less(2) than available processors(32)
4. How many documents you are fetching in your search query ie size param.
5. Search latency wrt to no of search calls
6. Search slow logs of elasticsearch(ES)

You can refer to [my 10 tips on improving search performance](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-search-performance/) ,and also tell me the values of some param mentioned in the tips.

Comment: Hello,Opster! Thank you for your time. 1)I have 2TB data. Every index has 50GB or more. Each has 10 shards and a replica. 2)A sample search time, without cached(recent searches) items takes 4 minutes. 3)I don't know where to get the heap size and I have 2 processors per node maybe by default(I read the ES set that but sometimes that setting is wrong). 4)I'm searching only for an item then a hash. 5) I search on all 30 indexes once. I need to search for the item until the last one in entire storage.6)I'm using ES API to make changes and see the requests result. How can I get this log?Thank you.

Comment: @WebDeveloper, please refer my another blog on slow-search deep dive https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-slow-log-search-queries-guide/ and please provide sample ES query with response and heap size can be found under JVM section of http://<your-es-host>:9200/_nodes/stats?pretty API output

Comment: "heap_used_in_bytes": 797019208,
          "heap_used_percent": 37,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes": 2147483648,
          "heap_max_in_bytes": 2147483648,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 197865216,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 261779456

Comment: @WebDeveloper looks like you are just using 2 GB of heap size which is very less based on your data, would stongly suggest to run the tool I mentioned in the link and share the report link here so that I can look and provide better recommendation

Comment: Is there a way to change these without affect nothing? What size I need to allocate there? I think I can't do follow your tips on that tool because of business privacy. Thank you!

Comment: @WebDeveloper, tool doesn't require any installation and I am afraid that you are dealing with huge optimization and in first glance looks like you have to tune a lot of param, i would suggest you to do the incremental optimization mentioned in 10 tips and measure perf gain, and most of them are about changing some settings and finding costly queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
1)I have 2TB data. Every index has 50GB or more. Each has 10 shards and a replica
```

That's to much.
The goal size for a shard should be around 50Gb. With your setting you are more around 5Gb Each.
You can shrink to 5 shards or less and force merge to 1 segment.
Performances should be improved a lot.

After that, look at other good advises provided by Optsters in his blog. They are all relevant.

Comment: Thank you, @Jaycreation. I tested that for only one index. I resized it to 2 shards but the search is still slow. When I'm trying to force merge it with `_forcemerge?max_num_segments=1` the request is too long and I receive `couldn't get the response`.

Comment: It should continue in the background.
You can use the GET my-index/_segment API to see if the merge has finished
num_committed_segments should be of 1. 
You should already have an improvement on this index. But performance issue can come from a lot of factors. Usually it need a specific audit